# How to do a program change in AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit

I am usind AudioKit's MIDISampler to play some notes. I use a soundfont with a lot of instruments.

After studying the documentation and the source-code, I did not find a way to do a program change in order to select a different instrument from the soundfont.

Any ideas?

```
var instrument = MIDISampler(name: "Instrument 1")
let soundFontUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundfont", withExtension: "sf2")!
try! instrument.loadInstrument(url: soundFontUrl)

...

// TODO: Do program change.
instrument.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 80, channel: 0)
```

EDIT: I thought something like this might work. But it does not.

```
let channel:UInt8 = 0
let program:UInt8 = 33
self.instrument.samplerUnit.sendProgramChange(program, onChannel: channel)
```

Answer (score 1):

MIDISampler extends AppleSampler which has some SoundFont specific methods. Try the loadSoundFont method. https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/110d2dfa0b798f76349922fdd1d23d660a16dc37/Sources/AudioKit/Nodes/Playback/Apple%20Sampler/AppleSampler%2BSoundFonts.swift